Adjust images to screen size in tensorboard instead of maximizing
I have a grid of images (2 rows x 4 columns) in Tensorboard. Each image is 640 x 480 and I have a sequence of those grids, representing the prediction changes in each epoch.
My problem is that the image is either too small...

... or too big when I use the "toogle actual size" button...

... and each time that I change of epoch, the images become again tiny (as shown image 1)
I could of course create the images with a smaller size, but for me it's also important to keep the size, in case I want to check in detail how the predictions were made. Someone in Stackoverflow in another question proposed to mouse zoom but it is also disturbing to do this each time I run tensorboard. I also saw the option of downgrading tensorboard but I'm not allowed to do it since I don't have privileges for that
I also checked at the arguments that tb.SummaryWriter uses but there is nothing related to it. In their code there is only the suggestion of using torchvision.utils.make_grid() which I already did.
Is there an option in Tensorboard (either by programming or in the page itself) to make the grid adjust to the screen without having to do mouse zooming?
